# Error executing the commands in the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I'm creating a script to get the counts from a table store it in a text file and trigger a mail to let the team know the count in table for the day

```
   #!/bin/bash

    today=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)

    > /tmp/score_cnt.txt

    FILE="/tmp/score_cnt.txt"

    sqlplus -S user/Pass@service<< EOF
    set heading off;

    spool $FILE
    select count(*) from score_tbl;
    spool off;

    count= cat /tmp/score_cnt.txt

    if ($count eq O)
    then (
    echo "Dear All,

    URGENT! Please check if the ETL execution is success as the todays count in Table is 0
    ") | mailx -S smtp=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -s "COUNT FOR $today : $count" -a /tmp/score_cnt.txt abc@gmail.com

    else

    echo "Today's count in table is $count!"
    | mailx -S smtp=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -s "COUNT FOR $today : $count" -a /tmp/score_cnt.txt abc@gmail.com

    exit;
    EOF
```

But I'm facing below issue as some of the statements are not executing. Can someone please let me know what is wrong in the script.

```
++ date +%d-%m-%Y
+ today=14-03-2020
+ FILE=/tmp/score_cnt.txt
+ sqlplus -S user/Pass@service<< EOF

  19127227

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "count= cat..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "if ( eq O)" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0042: unknown command "then (" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo "Dear..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "URGENT! Pl..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "") | mailx..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SP2-0042: unknown command "else" - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "echo "Toda..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "| mailx -S..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Comment: Varable assignment:  `variablename=value`  to store the command in a variable `variablename=$(command_to_capture_the_output)` The `$( )` is called command substitution. One more thing bookmark this: https://shellcheck.net to validate your shell scripts.

Comment: `if ( eq O)` is wrong, shellcheck should tell you that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%d-%m-%Y)

> /tmp/score_cnt.txt

FILE="/tmp/score_cnt.txt"

sqlplus -S user/Pass@service<< EOF
set heading off;

spool $FILE
select count(*) from score_tbl;
spool off;

EOF

count=$(cat /tmp/score_cnt.txt)

if ((count == O)); then
    echo "Dear All,

URGENT! Please check if the ETL execution is success as the todays count in Table is 0
" |
    mailx -S smtp=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -s "COUNT FOR $today : $count" -a /tmp/score_cnt.txt abc@gmail.com

else

    echo "Today's count in table is $count!" |
    mailx -S smtp=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -s "COUNT FOR $today : $count" -a /tmp/score_cnt.txt abc@gmail.com

fi
```

but I guess you could just:

```
count=$(sqlplus -S user/pass@server <<EOF
set heading off;
select count(*) from score_tbl;
EOF
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the support! I just used your second option and it worked.However, When I'm scheduling the same in Crontab. I'm not getting the counts. Could you please let me know.

Comment: @AishwaryaMishra, that's more likely a sqlplus issue rather than a bash issue -- it typically depends on environment variables to find the `tnsnames.ora` and thus identify how to contact the named `service`; cron jobs have a very minimal set of environment variables. Depending on where `sqlplus` is installed, you might also need a non-default `PATH`.